# Limit Elements on Screen while animating

Tags: javascript, animation

I have a script that slides Elements randomly from right to left.
But i'm running into an issue how to Limit the number of Elements on screen.
For now all Elements in Array are appended to DOM. But how to Split the Array to have only 6 Elements that will slide and the other are appended later on.

To illustrate this, i've made a jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/magic77/fwfv0kon/6/

Js Code

```
var getTemplate = function (id) {
            return '<a href="#" target="_blank" class="feed-post" id="feed_' + id + '" style="transform: translate3d(-500px, 0, 0) scale(1);">' +
                '<div class="feed-post-wrap">' +
                '<div class="feed-post-image" style="background-image: url(\'assets/images/8/artists-testbild-7aed80e8.jpg\');"></div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</a>';
        };

        var $stagetview = $('.socialfeeds'),
            elements = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // Append all Elements to DOM
            $stagetview.append(getTemplate(i));

            // Push Elements to Array
            elements[i] = $('#feed_' + i + '');
        }

        var animationInterval = setInterval(function () {
            if (elements.length > 0) {
                var firstElement = elements.shift();
                firstElement.testplug2({
                    y: fnc.randInt(0, 150),
                    speed: fnc.randInt(30, 120),
                    scale: fnc.randFloat(0.4, 1.01)
                });
            } else {
                clearInterval(animationInterval);
            }
        }, 1500);

    };


    $.fn.testplug2 = function (options) {

        // default settings
        var settings = $.extend({
            element: this,
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            height: 350,
            width: 350,
            startX: 1400,
            scale: 1.0,
            speed: 100
        }, options);

        var OBJ = OBJ || {},
            _this = this,
            // static width is needed for a proper calculation
            // in this case its 350px div width + margin: 20px;
            staticwidth = 390;

        var addListeners = function () {
            // delayed stage recalculation on resize
            var delayCalc = fnc.debounce(function () {
                calculateObjStart();
            }, 150);
            $(window).on('resize', delayCalc);

            // Pause/Resume on Hover
            settings.element.hover(
                function () {
                    _this.pause();
                }, function () {
                    _this.play();
                }
            );
        };

        var init = function () {
            // Update start X based on screen size
            calculateObjStart();
            settings.x = settings.startX;
            settings.y = fnc.randInt(1, (500 - (staticwidth * settings.scale + 10)));
            //settings.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (170 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
            settings.width = staticwidth * settings.scale;
        };

        var moveObject = function () {
            // Move Object's x position
            var velocity = settings.speed * OBJ._delta;
            settings.x = settings.x - velocity;

            // Reset when off screen
            if (settings.x < -settings.width - 20) {
                settings.x = settings.startX;
                settings.scale = fnc.randFloat(0.3, 1.05);
                settings.speed = fnc.randInt(30, 150);
                settings.y = fnc.randInt(1, (500 - (staticwidth * settings.scale + 10)));
                //settings.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (170 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
                settings.width = staticwidth * settings.scale;
            }
        };

        var calculateObjStart = function () {
            settings.startX = document.body.clientWidth;
        };

        var frame = function () {
            OBJ.now = Date.now();
            OBJ._delta = (OBJ.now - OBJ._then) / 1000; // Converts to seconds
            OBJ._then = OBJ.now;

            // Update Object Position
            moveObject();

            // Move Element
            settings.element.css('transform', 'translate3d(' + settings.x + 'px, ' + settings.y + 'px, 0) scale(' + settings.scale + ')');
            OBJ.rafid = requestAnimationFrame(frame);
        };

        // Public Function
        this.play = function () {
            if (!OBJ.isRunning) {
                OBJ._then = Date.now();
                frame();
                OBJ.isRunning = true;
            }
            return this;
        };

        // Public Function
        this.pause = function () {
            cancelAnimationFrame(OBJ.rafid);
            OBJ.isRunning = false;
            return this;
        };

        init();
        addListeners();
        this.play();
    };


    var fnc = {
        debounce: function (func, wait, immediate) {
            var timeout;
            return function () {
                var context = this,
                    args = arguments;
                var later = function () {
                    timeout = null;
                    if (!immediate) {
                        func.apply(context, args);
                    }
                };
                var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
                if (callNow) {
                    func.apply(context, args);
                }
            };
        },
        randInt: function (min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        },
        randFloat: function (min, max) {
            return (Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(4);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about something like this for the delay of > 6 elements: https://jsfiddle.net/fwfv0kon/9/ you could change the 1000 in the timeout to be greater to adjust the delay..

Comment: @Woodrow thanks for the quick replay. But there are two Problems. After "feed_5" all other Elements are "feed_10", in this case 4 times, so Elements 6,7,8,9 are missing. Here is a Update https://jsfiddle.net/magic77/fwfv0kon/10/

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/fwfv0kon/11/ that's my fault, doing a setTimeout inside the for loop..

Comment: @Woodrow ah, that is much better. I think the main Problem is the random speed of the Elements, so sometimes there are some more Elements on the Screen. After i increased your setTimeout to 3000 it goes more to the direction i need

Answer (score 0):

You could use array.splice to split the array. Hope you will find it helpful.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

while (a.length) {
 console.log(a.splice(0, 6));
}
// [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
// [ 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]
```